# C# Scroll text using DrawString

Tags: c#, text, scroll, system.drawing

I'm quite new to C# so excuse me if this is a stupid question. I would like to scroll some text from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen line-by-line. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: I'm open to all options!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're planning on writing directly to the Desktop, I would strongly suggest *not* doing this.

A much simpler way is to draw the text onto a transparent form (use the form's `TransparencyKey` property to achieve this), and then move the Location of the form to achieve the scrolling effect.

Answer (score 0):

On the screen on the form ?

Because if on the screen then you will need to import the DllImport("User32.dll")] and use method.

public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr dc);

If on the form easy way is to create a method that will change the string positon and put in in a look that sleep for a 100ms.

Comment: Well, I'm planning to write to the Desktop (I'm aware of the issues surrounding this) and not a form.